# Cannot load cloned model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**Keras**: 2.2.4

**TF**: from docker image tensorflow/tensorflow:1.10.1-gpu-py3

I'm having problems with cloning the model.

Here is the code:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import Model  
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import clone_model

input_layer = Input(shape=(4, 4, 3)) 
conv_1 = Conv2D(filters=2, kernel_size=(1, 1))(input_layer)
out_layer = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(conv_1)   

model = Model(input_layer, out_layer)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')
model.save('./test-model.hdf5')
model_new = load_model('./test-model.hdf5')

new_input_layer = Input(shape=(10, 10, 3)) 
cloned_model = clone_model(model, new_input_layer)
#cloned_model = clone_model(model)
cloned_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')
cloned_model.summary()
print(cloned_model.inputs)
cloned_model.save('./cloned-model.hdf5')
with open('model_architecture.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(cloned_model.to_json())
with open('model_architecture.yaml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(cloned_model.to_yaml())
model_new_cloned = load_model('./cloned-model.hdf5')
```

In the last command when I try to load the cloned model, I get an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-aebdef614797> in <module>()
     24 with open('model_architecture.yaml', 'w') as f:
     25     f.write(cloned_model.to_yaml())
---> 26 model_new_cloned = load_model('./cloned-model.hdf5')

/code/keras/keras/engine/saving.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    417     h5dict = H5Dict(filepath, 'r')
    418     try:
--> 419         model = _deserialize_model(h5dict, custom_objects, compile)
    420     finally:
    421         if opened_new_file:

/code/keras/keras/engine/saving.py in _deserialize_model(h5dict, custom_objects, compile)
    224         raise ValueError('No model found in config.')
    225     model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
--> 226     model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    227     model_weights_group = h5dict['model_weights']
    228 

/code/keras/keras/engine/saving.py in model_from_config(config, custom_objects)
    456                         '`Sequential.from_config(config)`?')
    457     from ..layers import deserialize
--> 458     return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
    459 
    460 

/code/keras/keras/layers/__init__.py in deserialize(config, custom_objects)
     53                                     module_objects=globs,
     54                                     custom_objects=custom_objects,
---> 55                                     printable_module_name='layer')

/code/keras/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in deserialize_keras_object(identifier, module_objects, custom_objects, printable_module_name)
    145                     config['config'],
    146                     custom_objects=dict(list(_GLOBAL_CUSTOM_OBJECTS.items()) +
--> 147                                         list(custom_objects.items())))
    148             with CustomObjectScope(custom_objects):
    149                 return cls.from_config(config['config'])

/code/keras/keras/engine/network.py in from_config(cls, config, custom_objects)
   1044             layer_output_tensors = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index].output_tensors
   1045             output_tensors.append(layer_output_tensors[tensor_index])
-> 1046         return cls(inputs=input_tensors, outputs=output_tensors, name=name)
   1047 
   1048     def save(self, filepath, overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True):

/code/keras/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

/code/keras/keras/engine/network.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     91                 'inputs' in kwargs and 'outputs' in kwargs):
     92             # Graph network
---> 93             self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
     94         else:
     95             # Subclassed network

/code/keras/keras/engine/network.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs, name)
    229         # Keep track of the network's nodes and layers.
    230         nodes, nodes_by_depth, layers, layers_by_depth = _map_graph_network(
--> 231             self.inputs, self.outputs)
    232         self._network_nodes = nodes
    233         self._nodes_by_depth = nodes_by_depth

/code/keras/keras/engine/network.py in _map_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
   1438                                          'The following previous layers '
   1439                                          'were accessed without issue: ' +
-> 1440                                          str(layers_with_complete_input))
   1441                 for x in node.output_tensors:
   1442                     computable_tensors.append(x)

   ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1_4:0", shape=(?, 4, 4, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

The summary of cloned model looks like:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)         (None, 10, 10, 3)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
input_1 (InputLayer)         multiple                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 10, 10, 2)         8         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10, 10, 2)         6         
=================================================================
```

And the cloned model architecture in yaml is:

```
backend: tensorflow
class_name: Model
config:
  input_layers:
  - [input_2, 0, 0]
  layers:
  - class_name: InputLayer
    config:
      batch_input_shape: !!python/tuple [null, 10, 10, 3]
      dtype: float32
      name: input_2
      sparse: false
    inbound_nodes: []
    name: input_2
  - class_name: InputLayer
    config:
      batch_input_shape: !!python/tuple [null, 4, 4, 3]
      dtype: float32
      name: input_1
      sparse: false
    inbound_nodes:
    - - - input_2
        - 0
        - 0
        - {}
    name: input_1
  - class_name: Conv2D
    config:
      activation: linear
      activity_regularizer: null
      bias_constraint: null
      bias_initializer:
        class_name: Zeros
        config: {}
      bias_regularizer: null
      data_format: channels_last
      dilation_rate: !!python/tuple [1, 1]
      filters: 2
      kernel_constraint: null
      kernel_initializer:
        class_name: VarianceScaling
        config: {distribution: uniform, mode: fan_avg, scale: 1.0, seed: null}
      kernel_regularizer: null
      kernel_size: !!python/tuple [1, 1]
      name: conv2d_1
      padding: valid
      strides: !!python/tuple [1, 1]
      trainable: true
      use_bias: true
    inbound_nodes:
    - - - input_1
        - 0
        - 0
        - {}
    name: conv2d_1
  - class_name: Dense
    config:
      activation: softmax
      activity_regularizer: null
      bias_constraint: null
      bias_initializer:
        class_name: Zeros
        config: {}
      bias_regularizer: null
      kernel_constraint: null
      kernel_initializer:
        class_name: VarianceScaling
        config: {distribution: uniform, mode: fan_avg, scale: 1.0, seed: null}
      kernel_regularizer: null
      name: dense_1
      trainable: true
      units: 2
      use_bias: true
    inbound_nodes:
    - - - conv2d_1
        - 0
        - 0
        - {}
    name: dense_1
  name: model_1
  output_layers:
  - [dense_1, 0, 0]
keras_version: 2.2.4
```

Also, I have noticed that when I clone the model without new inputs (`cloned_model = clone_model(model)`), I can normally load the saved model.

Am I doing something wrong maybe?

Comment: I have also opened an issue here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11857

Comment: I think your error message is incomplete, it looks cut at the end, can you check it?

Comment: Yes, I missed it while copying it. I added it now. Thanks!